# How can I disable Parameter Prompt at run time in Crystal Report XI?

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I disable Parameter Prompt in sub report at run time in Crystal Report XI? I used Ms VS 2005 and report also included. Other report features is the same Crystal Report features. Other report not show prompt at run time which are not included Sub report. Prompt appeared one is included sub report. so you may hv any suggestion. let me know pls. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and resolved this by modifying our code that prints the report.
Instead of setting the `ReportSource` of the `CrystalReportViewer` before setting the report parameters, set it after you have added all the report and subreport parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it with something very simple, I don`t know if it works in every case but in my case it did.

Solution:
Go to Properties of your CrystalReportViewer and set ReportSource=None

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps

1. Don't use CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport  or CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh
2. Set Report source from properties  to none
3. Report source must be assigned Dynamically
4. in your code have this sequence

   `REPORT1.Refresh()
   REPORT1.SetParameterValue(0, "some default value") 'assign some default value
   CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = REPORT1 'dynamically assigned report source`