# how to pass combo box value as a parameter to crystal report in c#

Tags: c#, combobox, crystal-reports

i am passing combox value as parameter to crystal report but when i run my application it asks me for the value, given below. How to avoid/skip this prompt dialog and directly pass value from combobox to crystal report?

[image]

this is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int16));
            dt.Columns.Add("month", typeof(string));

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[0].Value, row.Cells[1].Value);
            }
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ds.WriteXmlSchema("sample.xml");

            CrystalReport2 rpt = new CrystalReport2();
            rpt.SetParameterValue("name",comboBox1.Text);
            rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable Parameter Prompt at run time in Crystal Report XI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221370/how-can-i-disable-parameter-prompt-at-run-time-in-crystal-report-xi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing

```
rpt.SetParameterValue("name",comboBox1.Text);
```

with

```
rpt.ParameterFields.Item["name"].CurrentValues = comboBox1.Text;
rpt.ParameterFields.Item["name"].HasCurrentValue = true;
```

if it doesn't work try this

```
var param= new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterValues();
var paramVal = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramVal.Value = comboBox1.Text;
param.Add(paramVal);
rpt.SetParameterValue("name", param)
```

I have adapted the code from [here](http://www.it-sideways.com/2011/10/how-to-disable-parameter-prompt-for.html) for you

Comment: i am working in windows form.
rpt.ParameterFields has no Item field.

Comment: try `rpt.SetParameterValue(0, comboBox1.Text)`

Comment: gives the same prompt.